# Migrating Project from ASP.NET MVC1 to ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC1 in my project but now i am planing to move on ASP.NET MVC2.
What are the changes i need to do in my project to change MVC version? just need to change System.Web.MVC dll with MVC 2 dll or any other changes i required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the release post on Scott Gu's Blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx

This tool performs all the re-referencing for you:

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx

You might also want to grab the release notes off there MSDN download page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en

There are a couple of breaking changes to watch out for.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to follow instructions from here http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/ If this doesn't work for whatever reason, describe the problem here...